# Answered Calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've looked around for any people who have already done this but I haven't been getting a results. Basically following a formula off a website (here is a link) 
http://www.serebii.net/games/damage.shtml . I am using Python 3+ so here is my code. (note i have left out random number) i keep getting a syntax error.

```
level = int(input('Please enter your pokemons level :' ))
Attackstat= int(input('Please enter your pokemons special/attack stat : '))
Defensestat= int(input('Please enter your opponents special/defense stat : '))
Attackpower= int(input('Please enter your moves base attack : '))
answer= str('Is your move STAB? : ')
STAB= if answer == yes:
                      STAB= 1.5
else:
          STAB= 1
answer1= int('How effective is your move?')
resistance= if answer1== 4:
                           resistance= 4
            if answer1== 2:
                           resistance= 2
            if answer1== 1:
                           resistance= 1
            if answer1== 0.5:
                             resistance= 0.5
            if answer1== 0.25:
                              resistance= 0.25
damage= (((2* level/5 +2) * Attackstat * Attackpower/ Defensestat)/50)+2)*STAB*resistance/100
print (damage)
```

Comment: I know i have done it a long winded way but i wanted to make it as simple as possible

Comment: @Suever: look at the answer… ;)

Comment: In addition to @Clodion answer, you have forgotten `input` in the `answer1` input, and missing a parentheses in the beginning of `damage` equation.

Comment: Thanks guys you were all a big help my code is working now!

Answer (score 1):

Well:

```
resistance= if answer1== 4:
                           resistance= 4
            if answer1== 2:
                           resistance= 2
            if answer1== 1:
                           resistance= 1
            if answer1== 0.5:
                             resistance= 0.5
            if answer1== 0.25:
                              resistance= 0.25
```

give an error in Python. Just write:

```
if answer1== 4:
    resistance= 4
if answer1== 2:
    resistance= 2
if answer1== 1:
    resistance= 1
if answer1== 0.5:
    resistance= 0.5
if answer1== 0.25:
    resistance= 0.25
```

And better:

```
if answer1== 4:
    resistance= 4
elif answer1== 2:
    resistance= 2
elif answer1== 1:
    resistance= 1
elif answer1== 0.5:
    resistance= 0.5
elif answer1== 0.25:
    resistance= 0.25
```

And (same):

```
STAB= if answer == yes:
                      STAB= 1.5

if answer == "yes":
    STAB = 1.5
else:
    STAB = 1
```

And better

```
resistance = answer1
```

or

```
if answer1 in [4, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25]:
    resistance = answer1
```

Answer (score 0):

@Clodion answer is fully correct, but you can do it easier using `dict`s.

```
resistance = {4: 4,
              2: 2,
              1: 1,
              0.5: 0.5,
              0.25: 0.25
             }[answer1]
```

This uses inline creation of a `dict` and then gets value with key equivalent to `answer1`. Newlines can be skipped.

And, in Python there *is* the trinary operator in form

```
STAB = 1.5 if answer=="yes" else 1
```

What can be shortened to

```
STAB = (1, 1.5)[answer == "yes"]
```

because booleans in Python can be used as `tuple` indexes. `False` is `0` and `True` is `1`, so zeroth element must be this choosed when `answer != "yes"` and first when `answer == "yes"`.